# How do you invoke from an Excel macro, an applescript that interacts with the Excel spreadsheet?

Tags: excel, vba, macos, applescript

I am working with an application that exposes a scriptable interface with AppleScript. I need to invoke this AppleScript script from an Excel macro. The script should read information from the spreadsheet, pass it to the application and based on the results, update the spreadsheet. When I run the AppleScript by itself it work fine, but when invoked from the macro, the macro execution hangs. Below is an example that illustrates the problem I am running into:

VBA Macro:

```
Sub Test()
    OSA = "/usr/bin/osascript"
    SCRIPT = "/tmp/TestScript.scpt"
    MacScript ("do shell script " & Chr(34) & OSA & " " & SCRIPT & Chr(34))
End Sub
```

TestScript.scpt

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    tell active sheet of active workbook
        set value of range "A4:C5" to {{"a", "b", "c"}, {"d", "e", "f"}}
    end tell
end tell
```

If I run this script by itself, it works fine and updates the active sheet. But if I invoke it from the macro as above, I get a Runtime error 5 at the line invoking the script from the Macro.

Any idea how to get this done?

Answer (score 0):

That error indicates problems with the VBA syntax, a problem with the double quote of course. 
However, I would not run an applescript to run a shell script to run an applescript. Too many steps. Just run the script from the macscript line:

```
macscript("run script file ""Macintosh HD:Users:private:tmp:TestScript.scpt""")
```